# Flutter: The getter 'answers' isn't defined for the class 'List<Map<String, Object>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access 'second' from the below:

```
final basic_answers = const [
{
  'questionText': 'Q1. Who created Flutter?',
  'answers': [
    {'first': 'Facebook', 'score': -2},
    {'second': 'Adobe', 'score': -2},
    {'third': 'Google', 'score': 10},
    {'fourth': 'Microsoft', 'score': -2},
  ],
},
];
```

using this:

```
print(basic_answers.answers.second);
```

However it gives the below error:

```
Flutter: The getter 'answers' isn't defined for the class 'List<Map<String, Object>>'.
```

What would the solution be for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should familiarize yourself again with `Map` and `List` in Dart (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Map-class.html and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

`basic_answers` is a `List` containing `Map<String, Object>` elements, so doing `basic_answers.answers` will not work, since `List` does not have a getter for `answers`. Even `basic_answers[0].answers` will not work,. since the elements are of type `Map<String, Object>`.

To access values inside a `Map` you can use the `[]` operator (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html), so for example `basic_answers[0]['answers']` to access the `List` of answers. The elements in this `List` again are of type `Map<String, Object>` so directly accessing `second` will not work either. One options would be to do something like:

```
print((basic_answers[0]['answers'] as List).firstWhere((el) => el.containsKey('second')));
```

This gets the first element of the `List`, and then gets the value for the key `answers` from this `Map`. Since the value is another `List` we now can use `firstWhere` (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) to find the first element (`Map`) which contains the key 'second'